# Is there any 3rd-party skins for flex applications?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark, skin

I'm new to flex, and found the new spark library in flex 4, has a feature of changing skins.

So I wonder if there is any 3rd-party skin libraries to change the skin of my flex applications easily. I've googled for a while, but not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scalenine.com](http://www.scalenine.com) has some skins you can check out. A couple of them seem to no longer be available (bad links).

Comment: Found some beautiful skins, but it's a pity some of them no longer be available.